# Taxonomy Menus - How to set up menu that goes to a view filtered by two terms?

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I'd like to create a menu that looks like this:

Brand1
 - ProductsType1
 - ProductsType2
Brand2
 - ProductsType1
 - ProductsType3

When I click on a brand, I'd like to go the a list view of all products from that brand. When I click on a Product Type under a brand, I'd like to go to a view filtered to only products from that brand and of that type. However, the type is not defined by a Product Variation Type, they are all one Variation Type. I've created a vocab for types instead. (hooray for not finding a way to have one importer import to multiple product types...)

So, How do I create such a menu? It seems I'll need to link to a view filtered by two taxonomy terms. Is this somehow possible or is there another way around this problem?